# Adding Edit with Pyscripter back to Windows context menu?

Tags: arcpy, installation, arcgis-pro, pyscripter

Using Windows 10 64 Bit, ArcGIS for Desktop Advanced, ArcGIS Pro 1.2

I use PyScripter pretty extensively, and after I installed ArcGIS Pro (which installs Python 3), I noticed that I can no longer right-click on a python file and choose "Edit with PyScripter" anymore, even though the setting in PyScripter is set properly (Tools ==> Options ==> IDE Options ==> Shell Integration ==> File Explorer Context Menu)

How do I get this function to work again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding an entry to the registry... you can do the same by creating a new text file and renaming it to "AddToContextMenu.reg"  (the key is to rename the extension to .reg)  Copy and paste the following to the file, then run it to add it to the registry.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Edit with Pyscripter]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Edit with Pyscripter\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PyScripter\\PyScripter.exe\" \"%1\""
```